# $_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] is missing

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, yii2

This is my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . index.php
```

Even though I have added below line to my `.htaccess` file I cannot access `$_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']`.

```
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

When I'm doing `print_r($_SERVER)` I can't find `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION`.
I have googled for an answer but none of them worked.

Comment: is it shared server?

Comment: its shared hosting

Answer (score 9):

I have previously faced same issue and I solved by adding this line at the top of my `.htaccess` that is at the root directory

```
SetEnvIf Authorization .+ HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$0
```

Comment: root directory you meant where the index.php file is located at right??

Comment: yeah. In most shared hosts (if not all) it is `public_html`

Answer (score 3):

If you're using rewrite rules to pass this header - it may be prefixed by `REDIRECT_` Try `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']`.

But since 2.0.13 Yii has an abstraction for this, I suggest to use it:

- [`Request::getAuthUser()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-request#getAuthUser()-detail) to get user.
- [`Request::getAuthPassword()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-request#getAuthPassword()-detail) to get password.
- [`Request::getAuthCredentials()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-request#getAuthCredentials()-detail) to get both.

Comment: hey i don't get $_SERVER['REDIRECT_HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] either. I can't find the what is causing this problem

Answer (score 0):

if you run apache it can be retrieved with:

```php
$auth = array_change_key_case(apache_request_headers(), CASE_LOWER)['authorization'];
```