# Unable to get HTTP_AUTHORIZATION value from PHP after redirect

Tags: php, apache, redirect, basic-authentication

I have a PHP script that was previously hosted in a domain. I configured a redirect on the URL (apache mod_rewrite) to move the script to a subdomain.

Previous URL: https://example.com/script.php
New URL: https://sub.example.com/script.php

Here is the rewrite instruction in my domain .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^script\.php$ "https\:\/\/sub\.example\.com\/script\.php" [R=301,L]
```

The redirect works fine when I call my previous URL, but, when my script is executed, the variable $_SERVER["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"] is empty.

I can see from Postman logs that my Basic authorization request header exists in the request headers when the call is redirected to sub.example.com/script.php

But, the header cannot be fetched from PHP script.

And, when I call my script directly from the subdomain (using my new URL directly), the PHP script can fetch my authorization header as expected.

Is there something I can do to make it work :)

Thanks!!

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51806446/serverhttp-authorization-is-missing